# The measure of the boundary being zero implies the set is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assuming our set, $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $m(\partial E)=0$ (where $m$ is Lebesgue measure), why does this imply that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 2):

Because $E\subset\operatorname{Int}E\cup \partial E$ and opens sets are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Do you mean that a subset of a union of an open set and a null set is always measurable?

Comment: @Ilya No. Subset of  set of measure 0 is measurable, hence union of open set and such subset is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow your argument.

Comment: @PiTheMathemagician $\operatorname{Int}E\subset E\subset\operatorname{Fr}E$. But $\partial E=\operatorname{Fr}E\setminus\operatorname{Int}E$, hence $E$ is **disjoint** sum of $\operatorname{Int}E$ and $B$, where $B\subset \partial E$. But $B$ is measurable as a subset of a set of measure zero.